# Kinetic JS - Scale image to fit canvas?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm trying to scale an image down to fit the canvas. I know the usual way:

```
var width = img.width-(img.width-canvas.width);
var height = img.height-(img.height-canvas.height);
```

But I'm looking to do it with img.setScale(), based on 0 (0%) and 1 (100% of size). I'm not sure how to do that in KineticJS. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure `setScale` takes values between `-infinity` and `infinity`.

Comment: @Shmiddty Poor wording on my part. Fixed.

Comment: scalefactor = desireSize / size, for both, with and height

Comment: @philipp Thanks for the answer! I figured it out right before I read your comment.

Comment: Can you post the answer here and close this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@philipp's answer did it:

> scalefactor = desiredSize / size, for both width and height